# tensorflow object detection pre-trained models SageMaker deployment

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I tried to deploy EfficientDet model from tf2 object detection api to sagemaker using the instruction here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/tf.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeCv1.png)

and similar to this example notebook:https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-tensorflow-object-detection-api/blob/main/3_predict/deploy_endpoint.ipynb

- when i tried to deploy with

`model = TensorFlowModel(name=name_from_base('tf2-object-detection'), model_data=model_artefact, role=role, framework_version='2.2' )`

`predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')`

I received the following error: UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint tf2-object-detection-2022-05-28-10-46-50-583: Failed. Reason:  The customer:primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint..

what could have caused this error?
Thanks in advance!

Update: when i checked cloud watch i found this log error:

```
ValueError: no SavedModel bundles found!
```

Comment: Can you add more of the logs from CloudWatch to your question?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! 
I managed to solve this... the issue was that my model dir structure had to follow this format:
```
some_name 
    |__ Some positive number that represents version (For eg: 1) 
            |__ saved_model.pb 
            |__ variables 
                    |__ 
```
I didn't create a top file with a version number and apparently my saved model file wasn't recognized, but adding it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this... the issue was that my model dir structure had to follow this format:

```
some_name 
    |__ Some positive number that represents version (For eg: 1) 
            |__ saved_model.pb 
            |__ variables 
                    |__
```

I didn't create a top file with a version number and apparently my saved model file wasn't recognized, but adding it solved it.